# Fuzzy rule based system: Should rules contain all inputs and outputs?

Tags: matlab, fuzzy-logic

I am trying to design an FRBS using Matlab fuzzy tool box. The fuzzy system will be used to predict player's type based on the inputs and a set of rules defined by experts. 
I have 6 inputs and 4 outputs (types of players). The given rules do not concern all inputs. Specific inputs are used for each player type.

Is it imperative to include all inputs and outputs in a rule? 
Also is there a min/max of rules that an FRBS should include or does it depend on the experts expertise?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really. It is possible to create fuzzy logic model without setting whole ruleset. But there is a risk, that model will perform worse in some unexpected situations which would be handled by missing rules.

However, it is possible to figure out fuzzy rules basing on data. I personally used Wang-Mendel method and it worked fine for me: still 6 inputs and 4 outputs will be many of rules to deduce :(. Wang - Mengel method is described in this paper: http://sipi.usc.edu/~mendel/publications/Wang%26Mendel%20SMC%2011-12-92.pdf